# How to pass a bearer token correctly in the Azure APIM?

Tags: azure, api, oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-api-management

I am trying to pass a bearer token from another API that I have subscribed to via my API into my APIM.
I had the idea of adding inbound processing that adds a set-header that adds "authorization" and "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".
So I was wondering if this is safe enough, as I don't want my bearer token to be public, I'm not sure if this can be traced outside of the APIM itself.

Could there be a better solution?

I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/use-oauth2-for-authorization in the Microsoft docs, but I'm not sure if it also works if it's a bearer token not linked to Azure AD. But maybe using "send-request" puts me on the right track?

Kind regards

Comment: Provided that you using the HTTPS scheme, the **Authorization: Bearer TOKEN** header is secure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store your secrets in Azure key vault. Define the secrets in APIM named properties. You should be good to securely send your token - "myToken"

```
<set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
     <value>Bearer {{myToken}}</value>
</set-header>
```

Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-properties?tabs=azure-portal